# Evitar 2 valores repetidos en C#

Tags: c#, repetidos

Buenas tardes dioses y divinidades de la programación, recién he empezado a trabajar como programador y pues actualmente estoy viendo servicios en C# Net Framework y como BD uso Oracle, mi duda es que me han mandado a hacer una condición donde no debe repetirse los valores, es una modificación ya que antes estos datos se diferenciaban por un campo más que ya fue quitado, he consultado con otros programadores y la mayoría me dice que debo modificarlo en la base de datos pero no puedo ya que no me lo permiten, solo me dan el procedimiento con el cual debo trabajar, si alguien me podría ayudar o dar una idea de más o menos como resolver este problema le agradecería mucho.

```
 public List<ListaTipoRenovacion> GetListaTipoRenovacion()
    {
        List<OracleParameter> parameter = new List<OracleParameter>();
        List<ListaTipoRenovacion> lista = new List<ListaTipoRenovacion>();
        string storedProcedureName = ProcedureName.pkg_Generales + ".SP_LIST_TYPE_RENOVATION";
        try
        {
            OracleParameter C_TABLE = new OracleParameter("C_TABLE", OracleDbType.RefCursor, lista, ParameterDirection.Output);
            parameter.Add(C_TABLE);
            OracleDataReader odr = (OracleDataReader)this.ExecuteByStoredProcedureVT(storedProcedureName, parameter);
            while (odr.Read())
            {
                ListaTipoRenovacion listaTipoRenovacion = new ListaTipoRenovacion();
                listaTipoRenovacion.ID = Convert.ToInt32(odr["STIMEREN"]);
                /*listaTipoRenovacion.SDESCRIPT = odr["SDESCRIPT"].ToString();*/
                listaTipoRenovacion.DESCRIPCION = odr["SDESCRIPT_TYPE_RENOVATION"].ToString();
                lista.Add(listaTipoRenovacion);
            }
            ELog.CloseConnection(odr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ELog.save(this, ex.ToString());
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

Ese es mi codigo y este es el resultado que me da en el Postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo que pasa es que tecnicamente son dos items diferentes, pues tienen IDs diferentes, es complicado, ellos deberian decirte cual ID es el que deberia de usarse y en ese caso se puede filtrar facilmente la lista, por ejemplo te dicen que el ID 1 es el que utilizaremos entonces filtras el ID 2 con Linq

Comment: Los ID que debo mostrar vendrían siendo el 1 y el 3

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y pega en ella el código como texto. Con una imagen obligas a la gente que desea probar tu código a reescribirlo desde cero y es algo no muy bien visto enla comunidad. Un saludo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Si en tu trabajo te dijeron que tenias que hacerlo de una forma en particular, entonces son ellos quien debe decirte como. Nosotros solo podemos especular sobre cual deberia ser tu solucion...

Comment: A ver.. vos lo que pedis es que tu lista no devuelva valores repetidos? esa es la pregunta?

Comment: Saludos. *(como ya mencionaron)* Respecto a la imágen que compartes el **ID** *"es el problema"*; si no lo asignas con un **return lista.Distinct();** quedaria; ahora bien si necesitas conservar  el **ID** será necesario contactes a quien te asigno esa actividad y le cuentes el escenario con los datos que te entregan.

Comment: Por qué no un `lista.Distinct()` con un `IEqualityComparer<ListaTipoRenovacion>`? Puede hacer un `return x.Descripcion== y.Descripcion` en el `public bool Equals(ListaTipoRenovacion x, ListaTipoRenovacion y)`? Eso filtra las descripciones duplicadas

Comment: Lo ideal seria borrar el ID que no se utiliza, pero si no se puede eso porque capaz ese ID esta asignado en otros registros, seria agregar una columna de activo y filtrar de acuerdo a ese campo.